# Publish dataflow job status once completed onto Google Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Currently i am using Flex Template to launch a job from a microservice. I am trying to find a better way (than using job polling method) to get the dataflow job status. Basically trying to publish dataflow job status onto pubsub by datflow job itself when completed.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to make a Dataflow job itself send its status to a Pub/Sub topic.

Instead, you can create [logs exports](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export) to send your Dataflow logs to a Pub/Sub topic with inclusion and exclusion filters and further perform text searches on the Pub/Sub messages to deduce the status of your job. For example, you can create an inclusion filter on `dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"`, and, among the received messages, one that contains a string like "Workflow failed." is from a batch job that failed.